R ggplot and gghigligt
I am attempting to highlight values in columns 4 and 6 using gghighlight. While I successfully implemented this for column =  4, I have not yet achieved the desired highlighting for both columns simultaneously.
see the image
myfraction |> 
 ggplot(aes(pt, n_of_fraction))+
 geom_col(fill = "red")+
 gghighlight(n_of_fraction == 4, n_of_fraction == 6)+
 coord_flip()+
 theme_bw()+
 labs( y = "# Fraction",
    x = "pt",
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
theme(
plot.title = element_markdown(size = 10, face = "bold"), 
#axis.text.y = element_blank(),    # Hide the y-axis text
#axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
)


t would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

You may need to set a fill aesthetic if you have more than one value to highlight. Try adding fill = factor(n_of_fraction) to the aes() statement, and remove the fill argument from geom_col().

Try this:
myfraction |> 
 ggplot(aes(pt, n_of_fraction))+
 geom_col(fill = "red")+
 gghighlight(n_of_fraction == 4 | n_of_fraction == 6)+
 coord_flip()+
 theme_bw()

